# SAS merge in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sas

I am converting SAS code to Spark. In one of the data step SAS is doing merge.
I need to achieve same in Spark. Please help me to get this done.

SAS Code:

```
proc sort data=dat1;by mbr_sys_id clm_aud_nbr2;run;
proc sort data=dat2;by mbr_sys_id clm_aud_nbr2;run;

data want;
 merge dat1(in=a)
    dat2(in=b);
    by mbr_sys_id clm_aud_nbr2;
    if a and b;
run;
```

Spark code:

```
val want=dat1.as("a").join(dat2.as("b"), dat1("mbr_sys_id")===dat2("mbr_sys_id") && 
    dat1("clm_aud_nbr2")===dat2("clm_aud_nbr2"),"inner")
```

Output of SAS :
[SAS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEOl7.png)

Output of Spark:
[Spark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8TlO.png)

So SAS give only three rows but spark gives 6 rows, I am told to get the output as SAS.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Spark code, the result is as expected. 2 x 3 rows that fullfil the join condition. if you don't want this, you can try a left-join with the right table first

Comment: Yes, I know it gives 2*3 but how to get like SAS merge.

Comment: I'm not sure what the concept of "merge" does in SAS. Can you explain this? What is the semantics of this? Ok, I read it. SAS Merge takes one record from the first file matches with one record on the second file if they have same column in common. Join takes one record from the first file matches with all records on the second file if they have same column in common.

Comment: did you try to add an `distinct()` to the dataframe?

Comment: SAS merge is like join, but when there is many to many join,  it's done like this.
in Dat1 there are 2 rows and in Dat2 there are three rows.
so Dat1 first row is joined with dat2 first row and second row to second row of dat2
, next dat2 has got three rows and now dat2 ran out of all rows...now dat1 will keep on giving the last row of it's dataset and this last row will be used to join for rest of the rows in dat2.

Comment: try a `distinct()` to the end

Comment: I tried did not work. I mean did not give expected result

Comment: The SAS code isn't just doing an inner join it's also selecting the first record there. SAS data step merge should not have been used in this case (unless there were other variables on the BY statement) as many to many merges are not supported in a data step merge - that should be handled in SQL or some other way.

Comment: Are you sure those sorts don't have a NODUPKEY there otherwise, someone like messed this up.

Comment: Are you sure the SAS code you are converting actually works properly with this data?  You normally do NOT want to do a many to many merge in a SAS data step.  If you really want to replicate the way the MERGE statement handles many to many in an SQL like join you need to add observation counters to each dataset so you can get the first matched to the first etc.

Comment: I think you may want to look at `zipPartitions` with a transformation function implementing whatever `merge` logic you find in R.

Comment: @mazaneicha can you please explain the steps please

Comment: I'm just saying that it sounds like something that can be done via `zipPartitions` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zipPartitions[B,V](rdd2:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[B],preservesPartitioning:Boolean)(f:(Iterator[T],Iterator[B])=%3EIterator[V])(implicitevidence$12:scala.reflect.ClassTag[B],implicitevidence$13:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[V]